# how to disable the message this connection is not secure the logins entered here could be compromised in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am testing a login functionality in firefox with selenium in which when I get to the password field, it shows the warning as "this connection is not secure the logins entered here could be compromised" overlapping the login button, because of which instead of login button this warning receives a click. Can anyone suggest any solution for this?

Comment: try clicking some other spot in the screen so that the toaster vanishes or try clicking escape key to vanish it. Most of the time if you hit enter after entering username and password it will take you in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I have tried this and it is not helping out.

Comment: I tried again. it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I understand that some other toaster message is covering the button and so webdriver is not able to click it. We can do the following things to overcome this scenario.

1. Wait until the toaster disappears(in most of the cases the message will disappear in few seconds.
2. Try clicking somewhere in the screen so that the toaster vanishes and the button becomes visible.
3. In some cases, if we hit enter after populating the credentials it will probably log in. After entering the credentials sendkeys "Enter".

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: I waited very long time but my toaster refuses to disappear! I even cast adakadabra spell on it but still nothing happend, so I picked it up and hide it in a drawer, but message is still showing.

Answer (score 2):

That's a firefox setting. You'll want to

1) open firefox with the profile used by Selenium.

2) Go to about:config (in the address bar)

3) In your settings search for this: security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled

4) Put that setting to false.

5) Close Firefox and run your test

Comment: This solution is outdated. On versions 109 and above I doesn't work.